# Delay/Skip Token Expiration

Tags: okta, okta-api

**Tokens are valid for 30 days from creation or last use, so that the 30 day expiration automatically refreshes with each API call. Tokens that aren’t used for 30 days expire.**

Is there an api that basically doesn’t return anything but acts as a kind of dummy call to keep from token being expired when not used for more than 30days.

Basically this is when the test sites which uses token if not used for a longer period expires.

I am aware that refresh tokens is a way to get around token Expiration but rather than getting refresh token ,I just need to keep making a call for the token be to active.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So its typically recommend that we have a script hit one of the basic endpoints to keep on calling after every few days to keep the token from expiration.

Here's a response from okta forum

https://devforum.okta.com/t/delay-skip-token-expiration/22026?u=farhin